# Sudo without password issue

Tags: sudo, ubuntu-14.04

Having a problem with sudo. As the user `forge` I want to be able to run `sudo service php5-fpm reload` without having to type a password. I've tried all of the variants below.

```
forge   ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/service php5-fpm reload
forge   ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/service
forge   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/service
forge   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/service php5-fpm reload
```

But it keeps prompting me for a password. Tried loggin in and out.

```
# tail /var/log/auth.log
Sep 16 09:28:19 apps sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Sep 16 09:28:19 apps sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [forge]
```

This is the whole file.

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias SERVICES = /sbin/service, /sbin/chkconfig

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
#forge  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/service

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

```
$ which service
/usr/sbin/service
```

The problem:

```
$ sudo service 
[sudo] password for forge:
```

---

**This is what worked.**

visudo:

```
# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias SERVICES = /sbin/service, /sbin/chkconfig/, /usr/bin/service, /usr/sbin/service
```

`/etc/sudoers.d/forge`:

```
forge   ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD:   SERVICES
```

Tried to move the content of the `forge` file into `visudo`, but that didn't work.

Comment: What does the system log indicate?

Comment: Are you editing the file via visudo and not directly?  Are the permissions on the sudoers files ok?  You might want to provide the whole file as there might be something that is preventing what you are expecting.

Comment: `-r--r----- 1 root root /etc/sudoers`. Editing by visudo.

Comment: You don't say which UNIX/distro you're using, but on mine (Linux / CentOS and Fedora), `service` is `/sbin/service`.  Could you cut-and-paste into your question the output of `which service`, and perhaps an example of the failure so we can see exactly how you're invoking it?

Comment: @MadHatter Updated.

Comment: I find it quite useful to diagnose such issues using `sudo -l` to list the commands the current user is allowed to run. If I`m root, then I might use `sudo -U someuser -l` instead. Useful to tracking down problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

`/etc/sudoers`:

```
# grep -B1 'Cmnd_Alias SERVICES' /etc/sudoers
## Services
Cmnd_Alias SERVICES = /sbin/service, /sbin/chkconfig
#
```

`/etc/sudoers.d/forge`:

```
# cat /etc/sudoers.d/forge
forge   ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD:   SERVICES
#
```

test

```
[forge@localhost ~]$ sudo service
Usage: service < option > | --status-all | [ service_name [ command | --full-restart ] ]
[forge@localhost ~]$
```

Adjust *CORRECT* path to your `service` if needed, this may vary depends on your distribution, to find correct path run following:

```
$ which service
/sbin/service
$
```

Comment: Hmmm....this does not really look any different than what the user had but in a different format.

Comment: @mdpc different format that _WORKS_ (see my test)

Comment: Didn't work for me. Still prompting me for a password.

Comment: Got it to work now with `Cmnd_Alias SERVICES = /sbin/service, /sbin/chkconfig/, /usr/bin/service, /usr/sbin/service`

Answer (score 2):

You're giving the wrong `PATH` to the binary.  The `which` output shows that it's `/usr/sbin/service`, but you keep specifying `/usr/bin/service` in your `sudoers` entries.

Try

```
forge   ALL=(ALL)     NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
```

Comment: It still prompts me for a password, both for `sudo /usr/sbin/service` and `sudo service`.

Comment: Don't just tell us; **show** us - we need to see the relevant `sudoers` entry at the time of the sample output.

Comment: Updated the Q with what worked.